# Extract the zip file using php script

Tags: php

I have a zip file and i used the following code to extract that zip and put all extracted file in another location.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
echo $zip;
if ($zip->open("$pwd/wordpress-3.4.2.zip") === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo("$pwd/Repo/");
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

But i cant any extracted file whether it show 'ok' in browser. What is the mistake in the code i cant found. another thing to download the zip file from the "http://wordpress.org/latest.zip" site. i used the code written bellow. Here also i cant download the file.

```
$foo = system('wget http://www.myserver.com/file.txt ~',$output);
```

Comment: Why don't you use `$foo = file_get_contents("http://www.myserver.com/file.txt")`?

Comment: i have to get the zip file from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use:

```
exec('wget http://wordpress.org/latest.zip -O temp.zip');
exec('unzip temp.zip -d /somedir');
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `ZipArchive` needs a reference to the library containing that class.

Also make sure that in your php.ini file, you have enabled the library that enables zip files functions to work on your server. (The zip extension is loaded by default under PHP 5.3)

Again, make sure the directory you want to extract the files has write permissions.